# Biggest sales product year over year with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, dax, powerquery

I have a sales table of 5 products for multiple years and regions. I am struggling to get the biggest sales product year over year with Power BI. I know that I can group by year and get the total sales of each product, but what is the best way to extract which product had the biggest sales year over year? I have created a sample table:

| Year | Region | Product A | Product B | Product C | Product D | Product E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | America | 65 | 71 | 40 | 80 | 24 |
| 2020 | America | 50 | 56 | 36 | 44 | 45 |
| 2021 | America | 80 | 44 | 48 | 75 | 49 |
| 2022 | America | 90 | 65 | 55 | 52 | 99 |
| 2019 | Asia | 45 | 20 | 23 | 73 | 51 |
| 2020 | Asia | 55 | 33 | 54 | 52 | 50 |
| 2021 | Asia | 36 | 26 | 70 | 35 | 48 |
| 2022 | Asia | 23 | 64 | 77 | 28 | 28 |
| 2019 | Europe | 66 | 31 | 70 | 51 | 88 |
| 2020 | Europe | 56 | 66 | 8 | 60 | 53 |
| 2021 | Europe | 70 | 30 | 13 | 78 | 71 |
| 2022 | Europe | 89 | 78 | 45 | 67 | 80 |

**PS:** I have missing data in some of the cells, I am using null for those sells, would that change the calculation?

Comment: First Unpivot the Product to get a table with (Year,Region,Product,Sales). https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you

EDIT: It finds the Product in each year that has the greatest growth between that year and the next year ignoring region

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Region", type text}, {"Product A", Int64.Type}, {"Product B", Int64.Type}, {"Product C", Int64.Type}, {"Product D", Int64.Type}, {"Product E", Int64.Type}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Year", "Region"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Year", "Attribute"}, {{"Value", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows1", "NextYear", each [Year]+1),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Attribute", "NextYear"},  #"Added Custom", {"Attribute", "Year"}, "Added Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Added Custom1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom", {"Value"}, {"Next.Value"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Added Custom1", each ([Next.Value] <> null)),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Diff", each if [Next.Value]=null then null else [Next.Value]-[Value]),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Year"}, {{"data", each Table.LastN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Diff", Order.Ascending}}),1), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"NextYear","Attribute" }, {"NextYear","Attribute"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

It finds the Product in each year/region that has the greatest growth between that year and the next year

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Region", type text}, {"Product A", Int64.Type}, {"Product B", Int64.Type}, {"Product C", Int64.Type}, {"Product D", Int64.Type}, {"Product E", Int64.Type}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Year", "Region"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "NextYear", each [Year]+1),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Region", "NextYear"}, #"Added Custom", {"Region", "Year"}, "Added Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Added Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom", {"Value"}, {"Added Custom.Value"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Added Custom", "Diff", each if [Added Custom.Value]=null then null else [Added Custom.Value]-[Value]),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"Region", "Year"}, {{"data", each Table.LastN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Diff", Order.Ascending}}),1), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"NextYear","Attribute", "Diff"}, {"NextYear","Attribute", "Diff"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded data", each ([Diff] <> null))
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: you got the wrong numbers, the region does not matter, we only need to consider years, so 3 years 2020,2021 and 2022 should show 3 products that had the biggest sales.

Comment: edited answer to remove region

Comment: I cannot get the first row working, it seems it requires an absolute address, can you either change that line, or post a screenshot of the results with the new code?

Comment: Load your sample input into powerquery on a new blank file. Then use my code from the second row down. In other words, use your own code for row 1. Perhaps on your system it is Excel.Workbook instead of Excel.CurrentWorkbook

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on another approach I made this M code, which lists the 'TopSeller' values by year/region/product:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Unpivoted = Table.Unpivot(Source, {"Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product D", "Product E"}, "Product", "Amount"),
    SortedRows = Table.Sort(Unpivoted,{{"Year", Order.Ascending}, {"Region", Order.Ascending}, {"Product", Order.Ascending}, {"Amount", Order.Descending}}),
    GroupedRows = Table.Group(SortedRows, {"Product", "Year"}, {{"Count", each List.Sum([Amount]), type number}, {"Details", each _, type table [Year=number, Region=text, Product=text, Amount=number, Índice Geral=number]}}),
    AddedCustom = Table.AddColumn(GroupedRows, "TopSeller", each Table.Max([Details],"Amount")),
    TopValueExpanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(AddedCustom, "TopSeller", {"Year", "Region", "Product", "Amount"}, {"TopSeller.Year", "TopSeller.Region", "TopSeller.Product", "TopSeller.Amount"}),
    SortedRows2 = Table.Sort(TopValueExpanded,{{"TopSeller.Year", Order.Ascending}, {"TopSeller.Region", Order.Ascending}, {"TopSeller.Product", Order.Ascending}}),
    GroupedRows2 = Table.Group(SortedRows2, {"TopSeller.Region", "TopSeller.Product"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Product=text, Year=number, Count=number, Details=table, TopSeller.Year=number, TopSeller.Region=text, TopSeller.Product=text, TopSeller.Amount=number]}}),
    CountExpanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(GroupedRows2, "Count", {"Year", "TopSeller.Amount"}, {"Year", "TopSeller.Amount"}),
    SortedRows3 = Table.Sort(CountExpanded,{{"Year", Order.Ascending}}),
    ReorderedColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(SortedRows3,{"Year", "TopSeller.Region", "TopSeller.Product", "TopSeller.Amount"}),
    FinalRanking = Table.Sort(ReorderedColumns,{{"Year", Order.Ascending}, {"TopSeller.Product", Order.Ascending}})
in
    FinalRanking
```